# Leverage Browser caching working For css and javascript but not for images

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cache-control, mod-expires

In my website in htaccess I added

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year" 
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 2 days"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

After testing my site with
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights

It is showing Leverage browser caching is working for css and javascript but not for images (both jpeg and png)

Please tell me if there is any error in above htaccess

Comment: What is the expiration time it shows for images?

Comment: @hjpotter92 it is showing (expiration not specified) for all images

Comment: Are the images being served from the same host? Since you have `ExpiresDefault`, the caching would be atleast 2 days for all items served by the same host.

Comment: Yes Images are in same host but different subdomain

Comment: Till yesterday It was working perfectly in same https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights

Comment: How is the subdomain running?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104168/discussion-between-ghanshyamji-gupta-and-hjpotter92).